# How can I filtering objects of a model that their foriegn keys are not null in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have these two models:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and in views.py I want to return just 5 last questions that have choice. In other words questions without any choice don't return.
my view:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

What change should I apply in return statement?

Sorry for my bad English. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
return Question.objects.filter(question_set__isnull=False, pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: You do *not* need a related_name.

Comment: yes don't need but good to have to use as reference. Anyways I will edit my answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

re-write your `get_queryset()` as follows,

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(question__isnull=False,pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Choice.question_set.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

This uses following foreign key relations backwards, as described in the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

`Choice.question_set.all()` is used to get all `Question` objects that do have a choice by following the relation backwards from `Choice`.